Old movie about a man wearing WW2 gas mask, trapped in basement by piano on trapdoor
Trying to identify a B/W movie that I saw a segment of as a child in the early 1970s so it was likely from the 50s. Original could have been colour but our transmissions were B/W at that time.
I think it was the closing scene of the film where a man, wearing a WW2 era gas mask, was trapped in basement that he was hiding in, by a piano that had been wheeled on top of the trapdoor. He was calling for help but was only heard by a woman that I think he had been trying to convince that she was going insane because although we can clearly hear that she can hear the voice from under the floor, she says "it's just my imagination" or words to that effect. She then walks away as the credits roll leaving the implication that he will die or suffocate under the floor.

It's The Snorkel with Peter van Eyck made in 1958.




After Paul Decker (Peter van Eyck) seals windows and doors in a stylish European sitting room, he attaches rubber hoses to a snorkel. He lets gas escape through the room's lighting fixtures, allowing the gas to kill his dead wife, Madge, who is lying prone on the couch while he hides under the floorboards, using the snorkel to breathe while concealed. Decker remains under the floor as household servants discover Madge's body. Since the room has been locked and sealed from the inside, it appears to the local Italian police and British Consulate Mr. Wilson (William Franklyn) to be a suicide.
Madge's teenaged daughter Candy (Mandy Miller) has been traveling, and she with her dog Toto and traveling companion Jean Edwards (Betta St. John). Candy vocally accuses Paul (her stepfather) of the murder, but he has an alibi: at the time of the murder, he was just across the border in France, seeking peace and quiet at a lodging to work on a book he is writing. Candy is adamant; she is also convinced that Paul killed her father in a boating incident several years before. When Paul can produce a passport proving that he had passed into France, Candy is all the more determined to discover how her stepfather could commit the murder.
Wikipedia


Nice work! Nailed it - I'll have to sit down and watch the whole thing at the weekend. Well done working out that my "gas mask" was actually a diving mask and that my "piano" was a huge side dresser but I was going on a memory from 40 years ago.

@Gearbe66
A similar piano scene :) https://youtu.be/Z6ZBzLLjCX4t=2584
